# Pointing to a local variable

Tags: c, pointers

I would like help understanding this code:

```
void F (int a, int *b)
{
    a = 7 ;
    *b = a ;
    *b = 4 ;
    printf("%d, %d\n", a, *b);
    b = &a ;
}


int main()
{
    int m = 3, n = 5;
    F(m, &n) ;
    printf("%d, %d\n", m, n) ;
    return 0;
}
```

I am confused why this does not result in unexpected behavior. At the end of the function F, the value of b is 7. But when I return it is clear that nothing after ' b = &a ' impacts the value of n/b. 
I thought that pointing to a local variable would result in garbage/unexpected behavior when the scope changed, but that doesn't appear to be the case.

Comment: *I am confused why this does not result in unexpected behavior* - so you *expect* the *unexpected* behavior? Hm. I see a contradiction here...

Comment: at the end of the function `F`, `b` equals the address of `a`, and `a` is local to the function `F`.

Comment: So, what behaviour **did** you expect to be unexpected? Well, it results in _un**defined** behaviour_. Isn't that enough? How about reading the man-pages of functions you use? `%d` takes an `int` argument, not a pointer!

Comment: C11 draft standard n1570: *6.5.2.2 Function calls 4 An argument may be an expression of any complete object type. In preparing for the call
to a function, the arguments are evaluated, and each parameter is assigned the value of the
corresponding argument. 93) A function may change the values of its parameters, but these changes cannot affect the values of the
arguments. On the other hand, it is possible to pass a pointer to an object, and the function may
change the value of the object pointed to.*

Comment: This is `c++`, but same concepts: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope/6445794#6445794

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the [famous question on the topic](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6441218/335858), because OP falls short of setting up undefined behavior. In fact, he wants to see why the thing that he does is *not* causing undefined behavior. Voting to re-open the question.

Answer (score 2):

When you call F, you pass the value of m and the address of n.
In F, b is a pointer to n so that when you change the value of *b, the value of n is changed.  However, in "b = &a;" you are changing where b points.  After that line, b no longer points to n.  Instead, it points to a.  That line does nothing at all to the variable n back in main().  After that point, if you change the value of *b, you will change the value of *b and its alias, a.  It will not change the value of n in main.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I was under the (erroneous) assumption that the parameter int *b was synonymous with n.

Comment: *b "was" synonymous with n.  The line "b = &a" changes the meaning of *b.  After that, *b is synonymous with a.

Comment: Yeah, I think I overlooked that I was passing &n. For some reason I thought n was a pointer to an int as well.

Comment: Incidentally, you may want to change the title of the question, if possible.  This question isn't about pointing to a local variable after all.  It's about changing the a pointer parameter so that it points to something else.

Answer (score 0):

> At the end of the function `F`, the value of `b` is `7`

The value of `b` is not `7`; `b` is set to point to `a`, which has the value of `7`

> But when I return it is clear that nothing after `b = &a` impacts the value of `n`

Although `b` is a pointer, it is passed by value. `b` inside `F` behaves as if it were a separate, fully independent, local variable. Any modifications to it made inside `F` are local to `F`.

In fact, you cannot trigger undefined behavior in `main` by actions inside `F`, because `main` is not receiving any pointers from `F`. If you want to make undefined behavior, pass a pointer to pointer into `F`, and assign it to point to a local variable:

```
void CauseUB(int a, int **b) {
    *b = &a;
}
int main() {
    int x = 5, *y = &x;
    printf("This is OK: %d\n", *y);
    CauseUB(x, &y); // Pointer to pointer
    printf("This is UB: %d\n", *y);
    return 0;
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/077Zmq)